# Is Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() without await still executed asynchronous?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, dispatcher

I have a hard time understanding the connection between the asynchrnous methods of the dispatcher and async/await.

In my case I have an event handler that executes an operation on the dispatcher:

```
 private void OnEventOccurred(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     someControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, SomeLongRunningOperation());
 }
```

This should not block the UI thread, right? At least it feels like it in our application. What is the difference to the version with async/await?

```
 private async void OnEventOccurred(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     await someControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, SomeLongRunningOperation());
 }
```

This also works and doesn't seem to make a difference in terms of UI responsiveness.

Comment: The OnEventOccurred won't hold up the GUI. But SomeLongRunningOperation will.

Comment: Dispatcher.Begin/Invoke ensures that the code always runs on the UI thread.  Such code therefore always blocks the dispatcher loop for as long as it takes to execute that code.  The exact opposite of what async/await tries to do, nothing async about it.  Using BeginInvoke on the UI thread can be quite useful to solve a re-entrancy problem in an event handler.  Not a very common problem, you'll know it when you see it.

Comment: Your code examples don't even compile, so analysis of what they don't isn't really meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This should not block the UI thread, right?

`SomeLongRunningOperation()` will indeed run on and block the UI thread. The point of awaiting the `BeginInvoke` method is that your event handler will resume once `SomeLongRunningOperation()` has finished executing on the UI thread. So if you don't do anything after the call the `BeginInvoke`, there is no point of using the `await` keyword here.

When you do the following, the `MessageBox` will be displayed before the `SomeLongRunningOperation` method has finished:

```
private void OnEventOccurred(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(SomeLongRunningOperation));
    MessageBox.Show("SomeLongRunningOperation will be executed eventually!");
}
```

And when you do the following, it will be display after `SomeLongRunningOperation` has finished:

```
private async void OnEventOccurred(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(SomeLongRunningOperation));
    MessageBox.Show("SomeLongRunningOperation has been executed!");
}
```

So it's pointless to await the call to `BeginInvoke` if you don't intend to anything in your event handler after the method has returned.

Note that everything runs on the same thread here though. If `SomeLongRunningOperation` is a potentially long-running operation, you should execute it on a background thread. The easiest way to do this would be to start a `Task`, which you may await:

```
await Task.Run(SomeLongRunningOperation);
```

Answer (score 1):

`BeginInvoke` as the name suggests is always asynchronous. You're asking the `Dispatcher` (UI thread) to perform this operation, in your case long running, without blocking the calling thread. If you decided to use the `Invoke` instead, the calling thread gets blocked until the `Dispatcher` is done with executing the delegate you provided.

`BeginInvoke` does not imply that the work is done asynchronously on a different thread. What you would want to do is start this SomeLongRunningOperation on a different task and return it using the async await pattern as you tried in the second example. Something like this:

```
 private async void OnEventOccurred(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     await Task.Run(SomeLongRunningOperation());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

All the code assign to  `Dispatcher` runs on UI thread. Use `TPL` for long running tasks and `Dispatcher` to update UI only.

Comment: Or [IProgress<T> interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1)